# What's the correct way to add multiple classes in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm building a new template using Bootstrap 4 and compiling it with Sass. I have `.socialgraph-gadget` and I want it to both `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`.

Should I just do:

```
<div class="socialgraph-gadget d-flex justify-content-between">
  <!-- awesome content -->
</div>
```

Or remove the flex utility classes and add them to `.socialgraph-gadget`:

```
.socialgraph-gadget
{
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Or is there some better sass-y third option I'm missing like:

```
.socialgraph-gadget
{
  text-align: center;
  @extend .d-flex;
  @extend .justify-content-between;
}
```

This is a question I keep bumping into a lot with Bootstrap 4. There are just so many utility classes I can't decided if it's better to just add them on (composition) or define them in the class (configuration). If I go the composition route, I end up with so many classes it really clutters up the html. If I go the configuration route, I feel like I'm adding unnecessary bloat to my css files.

What's the rule of thumb or best practice here? Thanks. Sorry if this is a repost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the first option looks like the best. You could create a custom class in your own styles.css file if you would like to create a shorter way of doing this.

The thing with using helper classes (like the kind that Bootstrap provides) is that they could potentially clutter your HTML but that happens a lot of the time and you shouldn't worry too much about it. The advantage is that you end up saving time by being able to quickly drop these in when you need them instead of having to rewrite CSS.